# Wallpaper changer can no longer access/find home screen images on Samsung Galaxy A20/Android 11 to add to default album

Tags: home-screen, live-wallpaper

Until recently, I was able to add one image at a time to the default album by (1) downloading image from Samsung Themes, (2) applying it to my home screen, (3) adding it to Wallpaper Changer's default album. Since each home screen image overrode the last, I had to repeat these steps to accumulate all the downloaded images into the default album. Now, Wallpaper Changer isn't defaulting to the home screen image location anymore. How can I re-direct it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.